# Graphic card lights up but newly built PC won't turn on

Tags: motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, desktop-customization, computer-architecture

This is my first time of and I assembled my new PC and it is not starting for some reason. Though, strange my GPU is lights up but nothing else. I've checked the compatibility of each devices and they're all good. I've read through the manual and doing those below.

Here is what I did...

- Short circuit the Power Switich
- setting the CMOS (short circuit them)
- Removing all the connectors from Power Supply Unit, then reinserting them.
- Checking the System Panel Connector again and again. As I re-checked and re-assembled them several times and tried to power it on.

I've tried those mentioned above, however none of it worked.
Since I lack knowledge of hardware, I'm not really sure if there is anything more to do, honestly. And totally have no clue which part is the cause of the problem and if it is compatibility problem or motherboard malfunction or just simply forgot putting the connectors in.(I checked connectors are all set)

I've browsed on the web if there is similar situation but I could not find the case. Is there anyone actually had experienced similiar or same case as mine?

I am open to suggestions and willing to do some test performance, if I had to.

Thanks in advance.

-PC SPEC-

- CPU - i5 8400 2.8GHz
- MOBO - PRIME H270-PRO (ASUS)
- GPU - GTX1050Ti-4GB/OC/SF
- RAM - 16GB (8GB X 2 ) Crucial by Micron PC4-19200(DDR4-2400)
- HD - Kingdibian 2.5inch 60GB
- PSU KRPW-L5-500W/80+ (Made for the use in Japan so the voltage is 90V - 132V)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The motherboard was imcompatible with Intel CPU because its was 8th generation and motherboard should be specific as to which kind of CPU you're  inserting. Should've been more careful when I bought these devices, compatibility issue!